# Jquery slider with Slick slide

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am wanting to have multiple sliders inside of hquery tabs, the idea is that each tabs will be a category in Woocommerce but I am currently just hardcoding them in to initially get them to work.

The problem is when I move the slider html into the tab code the sliders no longer show?

Here is an exact replica of my issue: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8o1mLdk4/)

Once I understand and overcome this issue I am able to hen put in the loops I need.

```
$('.tabs-nav a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.tab-active').removeClass('tab-active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('tab-active');
    $('.tabs-stage div').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});

$('.tabs-nav a:first').trigger('click'); // Default


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake with your selector : `$('.tabs-stage div').hide();`
This means `hie every div inside '.tabs-stage' and his children` so every `div` is hided, so when you show the active slider with `$($(this).attr('href')).show();` it only show the slider and not the div inside it who are still hidden.

You should use : `$('.tabs-stage > div').hide();` (he `>` make all the difference) this way, it only hide the direct children off `.tabs-stage`.

[You FIDDLE edited](https://jsfiddle.net/8o1mLdk4/1/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I can now see the errors of my ways, I have noticed something a bit odd. When you click through the tabs it almost takes time for the slider to load the styles?

Comment: I think it's because of the `show` and `hide` from jquery, the slider have to be recreated each time. I'll take a look later.

Comment: I think it's good now. It looks like when hidding and showing the slider, slick need to recreate the slider, with the use of `$('.slider').slick('setPosition');` it kinda refresh it immediatly :

look here : https://jsfiddle.net/8o1mLdk4/2/

Comment: Thanks mate - that has cured it.